# Multiple jQuery selectors bound to the same event with a little change

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know that separating a list of selectors with a comma is actually binding multiple selectors to the same event or something else. So that's not the problem here.

The problem here is that I want to do something *just a little* different based on which selector was clicked.

For example I have two links:

`<a href="#" data-do="add">Add</a>`
`<a href="#" data-do="delete">Delete</a>`

Then I have a selector like this one:

```
$('[data-do="add"], [data-do="delete"]').click(function() {
    // do same stuff
});
```

For the `data-do="add"` I want to do a slightly different processing inside the event. Like if I could somehow ask if `$(this)` contains *add* then change something in the event and prevent the usual flow.

Just knowing how to know which link was clicked inside the event,  I'd be able to do the rest with simple `if` statements. The problem here is that I don't know how to do this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` inside the event handler refers to the clicked element, so you can use `this` to refer to the clicked element

```
$('[data-do="add"], [data-do="delete"]').click(function () {
    //general code
    if ($(this).data('do') == 'add') {
        //something special
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('[data-do="add"], [data-do="delete"]').click(function() {
    if ($(this)).attr("data-do") == "add"){
         // do something for add
    } 
    if ($(this)).attr("data-do") == "delete"){
         // do something for delete
    } 
});
```

It should also works with "data"...

```
$('[data-do="add"], [data-do="delete"]').click(function() {
    if ($(this)).data("do") == "add"){
         // do something for add
    } 
    if ($(this)).data("do") == "delete"){
         // do something for delete
    } 
});
```

Does it works? :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('[data-do="add"], [data-do="delete"]').click(function() {
    var elementType = $(this).data("do") == "add" ? "ADD":"DELETE";
    alert(elementType); //Switch by elementType
});
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/9n8gp/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('[data-do="add"], [data-do="delete"]').click(function() {
    // do same stuff

    /* you could use a simple if */
    if (this.dataset.do === 'add') {

    }

    /* or even a more complex switch */
    switch (this.dataset.do) {
       case 'add': 
          /* specific code for add */ 
          break;
       case 'delete': 
          /* specific code for delete */ 
          break;

    }
});
```

you could read the attribute with `this.dataset.do`, saving a couple of jQuery calls.

Here [some performance test](http://jsperf.com/html5-data-attribute-dataset-vs-getattribute) about `data-*` attribute access